# How do we reconcile Hebrews 12:2 and Revelation 3:21?

Tags: contradiction, revelation, hebrews, throne-of-god

**So is Jesus sitting on the right hand of the throne of God... or is he sitting on it?**

> 2 looking to Jesus, the founder and perfecter of our faith, who for the joy that was set before him endured the cross, despising the shame, and **is seated at the right hand of the throne of God.** -Hebrews 12:2

> 21 The one who conquers, I will grant him to sit with me on my throne, as **I also conquered and sat down with my Father on his throne.** -Revelation 3:21

Comment: Young's Literal, for Heb 12:2 has (for εν δεξια) _on the right hand_. If seated **on** the right hand, then it is implied that he is seated on the throne, but on the right hand side of the throne.

Answer (score 2):

The NT often says that the risen Jesus is at the right hand of the throne in heaven. Matt 26:64, Mark 14:62, 16:19, Luke 22:69, Acts 2:33, 7:55-56 (standing), Rom 8:34, Eph 1:20, Col 3:1, Heb 1:3, 8:1, 10:12, 12:2, 1 Peter 3:22.  See also Ps 110:1, Matt 22:44, Mark 12:36, Acts 2:34, Heb 1:13, Rev 5.

For a discussion about "seating arrangements", see my previous answer here >> [Revelation 3:21 Seating arrangements in the Heavenly Kingdom](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/66574/revelation-321-seating-arrangements-in-the-heavenly-kingdom)

Answer (score 0):

Jesus is sitting **on the right hand** of Gods throne, *not* on it. Jesus did *not* seek equality with his Father.

**PSALM 110:1** *The Lord said to my Lord, “Sit at My right hand, Till I make Your enemies Your footstool.”* (also see Luke 20:43)

His Father had a throne designated for his son ..

**LUKE 1:32** *He will be great, and will be called the Son of the Highest; and the Lord God will give Him the throne of His father David.* **33** *And He will reign over the house of Jacob forever, and of His kingdom there will be no end.”*

Although there is much debate on this, and convincing arguments could be made to support the alternative view. One being using the argument of the Trinity, that God and Jesus is ‘one’. However when considering ‘oneness’, you really need to take on board the Hebraic ‘viewpoint’ of oneness - but that’s outside of this questions parameters.

**REV 3:21** *To him who overcomes I will grant to sit with Me on My throne, as I also overcame and sat down with My Father on His throne.*

We could argue over the translation of ‘on’ [his throne]. The Greek ‘en’, which does *not* mean, nor naturally translate to ‘on’ - in the sense that Jesus is ‘on’ the throne. ‘en’ could also be legitimately translated as ‘by’, or ‘with’ or ‘around’. We really need to have a foundation of the Hebraic view of Gods ‘heaven’, that he *sits on the Mountain* of God, and on that mountain there are numerous other entities.

The Hebraic understanding of ‘on the throne’ can *also* be attributed to one who, although *not* on the [physical] throne, nevertheless has the authority as if they were.

So the point is, we really can’t assign an authoritative interpretation to Revelation 3:21, just one verse, and then use this as an argument to consider a conflict with other verses which have a wider [multiple verses] support for their view.